# MFC MDI Function calling vs SendMessage. C programmer trying to understand a basic concept

Tags: c++, visual-studio, class, mfc, calling-convention

As a Senior hardware EE, most of my programming time uses C for firmware and inline assembly as needed. I've been working on an MFC MDI which a few of you have helped me out beautifully. I am creating a settings dialog and moving away from the menu items to write to the registry for storage and retrieval of the apps `user settings`. I've Googled six ways to Sunday to try and understand basic `"Calling a function from another .cpp file class"` and many other variants of that to get my answer.....failed (Mostly like because I probably didn't understand their answers).

I have a master program reset that nukes the HKEY_CURRENT_USER key my app creates. Works great, no issues. Now, instead of being an item in the `"Settings"` menu with an item `"Reset App"`, I am moving that to a `button press` in one of the `property sheet/page dialogs`.

I have it working but I am unclear as to why my original thought of how to execute it fails.

So, in my application, I trigger this function:

```
void CApplication::OnResetProgramSettings() //Truncated function for StackOF clarity
{    
    // ask the user
    int DisableUserWarnings = FALSE;       
    if (DisableUserWarnings == FALSE) {

        if (IDNO == AfxMessageBox(IDS_WARNING_RESET_APP, MB_ICONQUESTION | MB_YESNO))
            return;
    }

    LSTATUS status = SHDeleteKey(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, _T("SOFTWARE\\Trains"));    
}
```

This is called from:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CApplication, CWinAppEx)
   ...other commands
    ON_COMMAND(ID_SETTINGS_RESET_REGISTRY, OnResetProgramSettings)
    ...other commands
    ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI(ID_SETTINGS_RESET_REGISTRY, OnUpdateOnResetProgramSettings)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

To make this work from my new `Dialog Settings` section, I implemented this:

```
void CSettingsReset::OnBnClickedButtonReset()
{
    // Global reset
    AfxGetMainWnd()->SendMessage(WM_COMMAND, ID_SETTINGS_RESET_REGISTRY);

    //CApplication::OnResetProgramSettings();
    //&CApplication::OnResetProgramSettings();
}
```

It works exactly as if I selected the menu item `"Reset App"` as mentioned above.

The property page is called `SettingsReset.cpp` and the above lives in `Application.cpp`.

From C land I would normally just call the function with the `application.h` included in the `SettingsReset.h` file like this:

```
OnResetProgramSettings();
```

I realize that doesn't work the same way in C++. You can see the two line items commented out from code above and uncomment below:

```
    CApplication::OnResetProgramSettings(); //Doesn't get called, static error if memory serves
    &CApplication::OnResetProgramSettings(); //Doesn't get called
    CApplication OnResetProgramSettings; //Creates an object I don't want/need... or do I?
```

So I am sending AFX messages to `"achieve"` the same operational result. My ultimate question what is the correct way to `"call"` the `OnResetProgramSettings()` in the Application.cpp file `FROM` the `SettingsReset.cpp` file? I've read about making the function `"Static"`, but I am unclear how to do that and/or why...and now would have two separate handlers for each function....i.e. `OnResetProgramSettings()` and `OnResetProgramSettings1()`....is that correct?

Is there a way to do this without having to use the AFX messaging to trigger that function?

Comment: That last part reads like a serial killer from the 80s sent a ransom note with random clippings from a newspaper.

Comment: The "or do I" bit?...LOL. I can see that now that you mentioned it.....or did you?

Comment: No, the random switches between fonts and quotes and dots and everything.

Comment: Sorry 'bout that, seems like all my previous posts where always edited because `keywords` where not `highlighted`..so now SO gets the kitchen sink of `pretty callouts`...in hopes my posts aren't edited.. LOL.

Comment: Normally you should not use the `WM_COMMAND` message to send your custom messages. Those messages are normally reserved for menu items clicking, toolbar buttons clicking, etc. If you want to send your own message, you should define one yours, like `#define WM_MYMESSAGE (WM_APP + 1)`. In the place where you want to notify, you do `AfxGetMainWnd()->SendMessage(WM_MYMESSAGE );` and in the place where you wanna be notified's message map `ON_MESSAGE(WM_MYMESSAGE, OnMyMessageHandler)`. Attention: `OnMyMessageHandler`return type is not `void`, but `LRESULT`.

Comment: BTW, this seems a bad application design to me. Your app class should not have any interface code. The message map should be in your property page class. And then there should be an handler function like `MyPropertyPageClass::OnButtonResetProgramSettingsClicked`
has the code of your `CApplication::OnResetProgramSettings()` and calls `AfxGetApp()->ResetProgramSettings()`, where the only line this last one has is the `SHDeleteKey`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two easy ways you can call a *non-static* member function of your application class from 'outside' that class. But they are *essentially* the same, in that you just need to call that member function *via* the actual application object (instance).

First, you can use that object itself. Somewhere in your code, you will have an application variable like the following:

```cpp
CApplication MyApp;
```

This will *probably* be in the "CApplication.cpp" file if your project was created using a Visual Studio wizard, and there will be a *declaration* in the "CApplication.h" header. Any source file that includes that header can then simply call a **public** member<sup>†</sup> function like this:

```cpp
MyApp.OnResetProgramSettings();
```

Alternatively, you can get a *pointer* to the current application instance (from pretty much anywhere) using the `AfxGetApp()` call, defined in the MFC headers; but note that this will have to be cast to a pointer to your derived class:

```cpp
static_cast<CApplication*>(AfxGetApp())->OnResetProgramSettings();
```

However, there is a very important caveat on calling members like this: you can't do it for functions that take arguments which, in the 'normal' calling method, are provided by the framework. So, for example, it simply won't work for an `ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI` message handler (which needs the `CCmdUI*` argument, provided by the framework).

---

<sup>†</sup> Note that message handlers are declared as *protected* when created with the class wizard, so you'll have to change your `CApplication` class a bit to make those you need access to in the above way public. But that's trivial.

Comment: Note: You can do similar stuff with your main frame window functions using the `AfxGetMainWnd()` MFC call.

Comment: Thanks for that... this is my fix and solves a lot of other issues I had on a back burner! I used: `theApp.OnResetProgramSettings();` and works as you describe. I do use the AfxGetMainWnd() often to write to my output status panes...I just couldn't get me head around the calling errors. Learned something new today. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI` macro creates a private (or protected?) member function, in your case `CApplication::OnResetProgramSettings`. That means you can't directly call it from another class (in your case `CSettingsReset`).

One way is to trigger the command through `PostMessage` as you did (except you rely on `AfxGetMainWnd()` instead of taking a pointer to the application class in your dialog constructor -- that's error prone if you later change the main window or use system notify icons, etc).

Another way is to move the functionality in a public class you *can* call directly, and have `CApplication::OnResetProgramSettings` simply call that new function. This avoids the middle step of sending to the message queue.

Of course this whole design is broken, all of this utility stuff should be moved out of any particular window class to a dedicated service class that encapsulates everything related to whatever that registry functionality is, and your windows receive and use a pointer to that service class. Think of it as an obsolete, bad version of MVVM, since you're using obsolete technology (MFC).

Comment: Thanks for this info...and it makes sense. I don't do anything with the `ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI ` I only use that to let it control/enable the menu item, I have no direct need to mess with it. I posted it just as an FYI on how I got the menu item to enable by forcing it to TRUE.

Comment: Also, the code was written in MFC and abandoned 10 years ago, the functionality of what it does is pretty rare, so I picked it up and have been reworking it since. I would have started anew if it were a ground up effort. Thx.